# Simplicial homology of sphere with bars.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a space obtained by inserting $n$ vertical bars into $S^2$. I want to compute simpicial homology of this space.

I am going to start with just one bar, the triangulation I have is the following:

[image]

Here, the two $\Delta^2$ complexes form the sphere as usual and $k$ is the bar. I am not sure I have done it correctly, because right now it seems to me that I have drawn a triangulation of $S^1\vee S^2$, so the bar should really have two distinct vertices in the interiors of the triangles and I would have to divide each triangle into 3 smaller triangles to compute the homology, but let me proceed with this space anyway...

So I have

$$
0\xrightarrow{\partial_3} C_2^\Delta(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_2} C_1^\Delta(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_1} C_0^\Delta(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_0} 0
$$

where
$$
C_0^\Delta(X)=\mathbb{Z}[v_0, v_1, v_2],
$$
$$
C_1^\Delta(X)=\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,k],
$$
$$
C_2^\Delta(X)=\mathbb{Z}[L,R],
$$
where $L$ is the left triangle and $R$ is the right triangle. Let me compute the homology groups:

- $H_0^\Delta(X)=\ker \partial_0 /\operatorname{im} \partial_1$, here $\ker \partial_0=\mathbb{Z}[v_0, v_1, v_2]$. An arbitrary element of $C_1^\Delta(X)$ looks like $ma+nb+pc+qk$ for $m,n,p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$, the image is 
  $$
  \partial_1(ma+nb+pc+qk)=m(v_1-v_0)+n(v_2-v_1)+p(v_2-v_0).
  $$
  In terms of generators, it is easy to check that 
  $$
  \ker \partial_0=\mathbb{Z}[v_0, v_1, v_2]=\mathbb{Z}[v_2, v_2-v_0, v_2-v_1],
  $$
  $$
  \operatorname{im} \partial_1=\mathbb{Z}[v_2-v_1, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0]=\mathbb{Z}[2v_2, v_2-v_0, v_2-v_1].
  $$
  Therefore,
  $$
  H_0(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2.
  $$
- $H_1^\Delta(X)=\ker \partial_1/\operatorname{im} \partial_2$, from the above it is clear that $\ker \partial_1=\mathbb{Z}[a+b-c, k]$and 
  $$
  \partial_2(L)=\partial_2(R)=a+b-c,
  $$
  from which it follows that 
  $$
  H_1^\Delta(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}
  $$
- $H_2^\Delta(X)=\ker \partial_2$, since $\partial_3$ is just the zero map.
  $$
  \partial_2(mL+nR)=m(a+b-c)+n(a+b-c)=0 \Leftrightarrow m=-n
  $$
  so $\ker \partial_2\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

In conclusion, I have 
$$
H_n^\Delta(X)=\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}/2, n=0, \\ \mathbb{Z}, n=1,2, \\ 0, n\geq 0. \end{cases}
$$
My question is have I done the drawing correctly and have I at least computed the homology of the drawing correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "inserting $n$ vertical bars into $S^2$." Could you elaborate?

Comment: Qiaochu, if we regard $S^2$ as a subset of $\mathhbb{R}^3$, then a vertical bar is a bar inside the sphere which is parallel to the $z$-axis with vertices on $S^2$.

Comment: Okay. Then $S^2$ with a bar has homology $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}$. It's impossible for $H_0$ to have torsion. Adding a bar adds a $\mathbb{Z}$ to $H_1$ and does nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a sign error in concluding $v_1-v_0 = 2v_2$ before you deduced $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}/2$. The vector $v_1 - v_0$ in the image of $\partial_1$ is actually redundant because $v_1-v_0 = -(v_2-v_1) + (v_2-v_0)$, so the image is just spanned by $v_2-v_0$ and $v_2-v_1$, which gives you the correct group $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$.

When you add a 1-cell in this way, since it is not in the boundary of any of your two cells, it doesn't killed when you take homology, so as Qiaochu already said it just adds a $\mathbb{Z}$ to $H_1(X)$. Up to homotopy you are just wedging with $S^1$ so there is no surprise here.